# Is replicated meat in “Star Trek” considered to be vegetarian/vegan?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I was watching a clip from the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode, “[Sins of The Father](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sins_of_The_Father_(episode))” (S03E17) where [Kurn](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kurn) (Worf’s younger brother) says:

> “I shall try some of your burned replicated bird meat.”

But just before this, Geordi La Forge states:

> “It’s not dead it’s been replicated… And you do understand that we cook most of our food?”

Knowing that Geordi states the bird is not “dead” but it is replicated, could the meal of “burned replicated bird meat” be considered to be vegetarian/vegan? Is the topic of the ethics of replicated meat ever discussed in the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* or other properties in the *Star Trek* franchise?

[image: Captain Picard carves into the burned replicated bird meat.]

---

***In-universe explanation preferred, but any “behind the scenes” discussions about this will be considered valid as well.***

Comment: The answer depends 100% on your definition of vegetarian. Someone who doesn't eat meat (and considers themselves vegetarian) due to meat protein allergy (yes, such a thing sadly exists) wouldn't care one bit if the meat is replicated or not.

Comment: Tempted to migrate this to the [veg.se] SE site :-)

Comment: Reminds me Clarke's "Food of the Gods" short story set in the future, where the person who was being questioned about the popularity of a newly released meat recipe, had to introduce an archaic word - "Cannibalism"

Comment: If replicated meat became common in industry, you can guess that a majority of people would eat replicated meat and refuse to eat animal meat, but a minority of people would still eat animal meat and another minority of people would refuse to eat meat not even replicated meat. Words would evolve accordingly. Today we only have words "vegetarian" and "vegan" and we don't even have a word for "not vegetarian", but in reality there exist many more different diets. For instance we don't have a word to distinguish between "eat fish but no other meat" and "don't eat meat at all, not even fish meat"

Comment: @Stef - oh, we do. In the software I write, we have a need to specify pretty detailed dietary needs for people. "Eats only fish" vegetarian is pescatarian. And "no meat vegetarian" is lacto-ovo vegetarian. Just so you know I'm not making these things up, here are Wiki links :D

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pescetarianism

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacto-ovo_vegetarianism

Comment: The discussion on types of vegetarianism was interesting but getting rather long and tangential to the actual question at hand. **The comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151086/discussion-on-question-by-giacomo1968-is-replicated-meat-in-star-trek-consider); please do not continue the discussion here.** Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Not sure if this qualifies. But one quote that seems to be at least related is from S01E07, "[Lonely Among Us](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lonely_Among_Us_(episode))" in which:

**Commander Riker** makes the statement:

> "We no longer enslave animals for food purposes."

**The alien [Badar N'D'D](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Badar_N%27D%27D)** comments:

> "But we have seen Humans eat meat."

**Commander Riker** goes on to say:

> "You've seen something as fresh and tasty as meat, but inorganically materialized, out of patterns used by our transporters."

Thus, I would suggest to your question on ethics, in that time period crew members consider the 'meat' made in replicator as comparable to the type of protein/'meat' we see assembled in an Impossible Burger or a Beyond Burger today. I.e. it is protein. But not from an animal. All the vegetarians I happen to know (admittedly not a scientific sampling LOL) consider those meat alternatives as vegetarian. Thus ethically is is valid to eat.

That would not necessarily apply to those that are vegetarian for health reasons. But your question was on the ethics side.

That said, I would not necessarily consider those on *Star Trek: The Next Generation* to be vegans either. We saw in at least one instance they ate eggs: S02E13 "[Time Squared](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1C-i7J9ZLuM)."

Finally, from an out of universe perspective, in his 1991 [*Humanist* interview](https://trekcomic.com/2016/11/24/gene-roddenberrys-1991-humanist-interview/) Roddenberry states:

> "My philosophy about the use of animals has changed. I am not yet a vegetarian, but I don’t feel comfortable as a meat eater knowing a lot of the things that go on to put meat on the table."

Thus, I would suggest Roddenberry looked at replicators as a way to satisfy the desire for a meat like protein without the ethical concerns he felt.  I.e. a way to be a vegetarian but still enjoy 'meat'.

Comment: +1, but I do want to note one important caveat.  People who avoid meat (especially red meat) because of allergies to proteins in the meat may not be able to eat replicated meat either if it duplicates the same proteins.

Comment: As a vegetarian, personally, I would be happy to eat lab-grown meat. But I certainly know vegetarians who have said they will not do so, because animals must have been harmed early on in the research required to grow the meat. So the idea that it's fine for vegetarians because any particular given piece of lab-grown meat hasn't directly come from an animal is false.

Comment: Do we know if the eggs they eat are from a replicator or from a live animal?

Comment: I always imagined that they had used the transporter to beam, say, a cooked turkey into the pattern buffer, and then just kept "beaming out" copies of it.  But I suppose if that was ethically troubling, they could instead beam in a live turkey, beam it back out again while retaining the pattern, then beam out another copy with everything but the head, cook that, and beam _that_ into the pattern buffer.  Is... is that better?

Comment: Doesn't Ben Sikso's dad run a replicator-free restaurant that serves shrimp creole?

Comment: I have a problem with this answer. The original "in-universe" purpose of a transporter was to deliver people from one point to another: they remained alive, therefore by definition they remained meat. Therefore food generated from "patterns used by our transporters" should retain its designation (i.e. meat etc.).

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd True, but in-universe, there's a distinction between the transporters and the replicators. They're clearly related technology, but replicators are unable to produce copies of the same quality as the transporters, and in particular with food, it's often said that many people prefer non-replicated food (or food cooked from replicated raw materials). That said, it's hard to see how you would have ethical problems with using replicated meat and at the same time have no ethical problems with using transporters to move people/animals (of course, in-universe, some _do_ ).

Comment: I've **[moved the comments to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151085/discussion-on-answer-by-beichst-is-replicated-meat-in-star-trek-considered-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** The discussion on the types of vegetarian and how it applies to the Q/A was interesting but getting long and rather tangential. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @JoeW Both.  Memory Alpha has a page on the subject of [scrambled eggs](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scrambled_eggs) with examples of  replicated and real eggs, and some of unknown origin.  Specifically, in the TNG episode Time Squared Riker prepares real 'Owon eggs as an omelette, but only Worf found them palatable.

Comment: @Luaan I always got the impression the bias against replicated food was a combination of pure psychology and the lack of variation, not because the food itself was imperfectly copied.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you The bias is those things you mentioned, but there *is* a difference between the resolution of the transporter and the replicator.  I don't think you can *taste* those differences, any more than people can really hear the difference between copper cables and gold plated audio cables.

Comment: @DavidW.  Correct. As I noted in my answer, those that are vegetarian for health reasons as you suggest may not be able to eat replicated meat either.

Comment: Mile's O'Brien was implied to have been raised on non-replicated meat in TNG's "The Wounded" so replicator-tarianism is not universal among humans. Keiko was incredulous at touching real meat, so people that aren't accustomed to it apparently are uncomfortable with the idea.

Answer (score 2):

## Is a copy of a steak ethical?

The replicator creates meat out of thin <strike>air</strike> energy, but where did the pattern for that meat come from?

Two possibilities...

### If replicator patterns are programmed...

...replicated meat is like a painting of meat. No animal was harmed in the making of the pattern. There's no ethical issue. It's someone's idea of meat.

Maybe that's why people say replicated food tastes wrong; they've had the real thing.

### If replicator patterns are scanned...

...replicated meat is like a photo of meat. While no animal was harmed to make the copy, a real animal was killed for the pattern.

This raises ethical issues similar to using research derived using unethical practices. On the one hand, that replicated meat required an animal to die, and by eating replicated meat you're creating demand for more patterns and more animals to die for those patterns. On the other hand, using the pattern doesn't kill more animals, and probably saves many animals by supplying the demand for meat.

---

I think it's the case that while replicators can be programmed, the basic patterns are scanned; the programming is like remixing. On the show its often commented that replicated food is molecularly indistinguishable from regular food, but how would they know replicated meat is indistinguishable from real meat if they didn't have real meat to check it against?

Comment: Actually, considering the scanning capabilities that exist in-universe, it could also be that someone scanned a living animal and *simulated* killing and cooking its flesh... while the template animal remains alive and well. If you need even more fidelity, just make a transporter duplicate of the animal you want, sans brain, and what's the foul?

Comment: @Matthew How did they write an accurate simulation without killing and cooking some animals to get data for the simulation? "*make a transporter duplicate of the animal you want, sans brain*" an interesting (if oddly grisly) ethical escape hatch; it's like real life lab grown meat.

Comment: Maybe they cooked an early transporter accident and used that as the model, which is why it tastes a bit odd.

Comment: Why do scanned replicator patterns require killing the animal? The same universe can transport humans by scanning them and rebuilding them elsewhere. That isn't considered killing humans.

Comment: @Abigail, there is intermittently some hand-waving about a "mind matrix" that suggests that transporters really are *transporting* and not just building a copy and destroying the original. OTOH, there are transporter "accidents" that make no sense if that's the case. Reality, however, is that the show isn't entirely consistent with its own rules, so... (But in any case, yes, existence of transporters especially suggests some possible "escape hatches" to being able to create "real" meat without "killing" something in the process.)

Comment: @Abigail Let's say you're replicating a cooked steak. They need to have scanned a real cooked steak for the pattern. To get real steak you have to butcher a real animal.

Comment: Two issues.  First, replicators don't create matter from energy.  Federation ships carry stores of raw materials used to create replicated items.  And waste products are broken down to maintain those stores. Second, just because an animal was scanned, doesn't mean the animal was killed.

Comment: @Schwern They could first scan a live cow, replicate only the cut they are interested in, cook that, then scan the cooked steak.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile To your second point, that's the open question. To replicate a cooked steak, must the replicator scan a cooked steak? Or can it scan a cow and then extrapolate a cooked steak? I don't know, and I don't know if there's much canon support for either, but we can discuss the ethics of either situation.

Comment: @Abigail Clever, tho I don't know if extracting a slice of a live cow will give the same result as butchering; they would need to simulate exsanguination (the draining of blood). Ethically, it's similar to lab-grown meat.

Answer (score -2):

The original "in-universe" purpose of a transporter was to deliver people from one point to another: they remained alive, therefore by definition they remained meat. Therefore food generated from "patterns used by our transporters" should retain its designation (i.e. meat etc.).

Comment: But a replicator isn't the same as a transporter, even if it's derived from the same technology. Even if it was, beaming synthetic protein and fat molecules onto a plate in an arrangement that was indistinguishable from a steak wouldn't mean it came from a cow

Comment: This calls into question whether the person being transported is the same person that steps onto the platform. If your bones, protein patterns and emergent conciousness is copied to the planet surface and your original mass is deleted from the platform, is that the same person? Is  [Thomas Riker](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thomas_Riker) as much the real Riker as our real Riker?

Comment: @Jacques when a person is clinical dead, then reanimated, is it still the same person or did the person die and a new person with the same body and memory created? Is the person waking up in the morning really the same person as the person that went to sleep the previous day? It’s even not for sure whether the continuity from the person you were a second ago to your current state is a thing. We pretend that it exist despite all of your body’s atoms get replaced over some years, so we have nothing in common with that person some years ago (except for some patterns)

Comment: Regarding the identity of a transported or replicated individual as "original" or not, you might be interested in the recent novel "The Punch Escrow" (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32446949-the-punch-escrow) by Tal M. Klein, in which that question is a significant plot point.

Comment: @Holger Us humans sure like to ponder these philosophical problems... meanwhile, it seems that nature couldn't care less...

Comment: @ChrisH That is speculation. The in-universe statement is explicitly "patterns used by our transporters" which does not make that distinction.